# Git: syncing my fork and fixing conflicts

Tags: git, github, git-merge, merge-conflict-resolution

Hi I have forked a repository. Several months have passed and I want to get it back in sync with the original repo. I have added several extra files in my own repo and added some files to gitignore.
I have read that you can do this online since march 6 or something but it shows: 
[image]

Some binary files need merge? why can't I just get the remote version?
[image]

git status:
[image]

I always have trouble with conflicts and .orgin files. Perhaps I am handling kdiff3 wrong? I could use a few pointers. Too bad that the official windows client (wpf) does not help out with getting back in sync with the origin remote.

**edit** as @ppittle suggested, I tried the sourcetree client and wanted to resolve a dll thing by clicking on resolve using theirs and it gave me:
[image]

Comment: Try using [SourceTree](http://www.sourcetreeapp.com/), a free Git client for Windows (and Mac).  It wont magically fix your conflicts, but it makes working with git much easier than using the official client / command line.

Comment: This might also help: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fdK_q3Pcp9s